# How to plot heatmap function over the unit circle

Tags: plotting

I have a function $Z(r, \theta)$ that I would like to plot over the unit disk. I could of course plot it as $Z(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \arctan(y/x))$, but the best I can do with this is a square plot. I would like a plot defined from $0<R<1$ and $0<\theta<2\pi$, such that it looks something like the plots shown here:

[image: Zernike polynomial plots]

How can I make *Mathematica* generate a plot like this? Thank you!

Comment: You might be interested in `RegionFunction`.

Comment: Ah that works perfectly - thank you!! Though I do wonder if Mathematica has something more intuitive built in, as it seems like a common enough application.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm still leaving this open for a solution as this method doesn't _quite_ work - using $\arctan(y/x)$ causes discontinuities at x=0 that mess up the way the plot comes out.

Comment: That's because you have to use two-argument arctangent (`ArcTan[x, y]`) for the purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my attempt to plot the [Zernike functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zernike_polynomials) on the unit disk:

```
ZernikeZ[n_Integer, m_Integer, r_, θ_] /; -n <= m <= n := 
         If[m < 0, Sin[m θ], Cos[m θ]] ZernikeR[n, m, r]

Table[DensityPlot[ZernikeZ[n, m, Norm[{x, y}], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ Disk[],
                  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"ThermometerColors",  "Reverse"},
                                              LogisticSigmoid[2 #]] &), 
                  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> False, 
                  PlotPoints -> 55],
      {n, 0, 4}, {m, -n, n, 2}] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: Zernike on a disk]

Comment: (Older versions of *Mathematica* can use `RegionFunction` instead.)

Comment: Much older ones ... v9 accepts `Disk[ ]`

Comment: Is the `LogisticSigmoid[ ]` in there for pure Fermi love, or is something really useful?

Comment: @bel, it allows me to map $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$, with $0$ being the white(-ish) color, and positive and negative values mapped to the extreme colors. I've used this rescaling before on this site...

Comment: Ah, OK.nice one.Don't remember seeing it used like this before, but the German doctor is always mumbling in my ear trying to distract me, so ...