# Set a fixed colour scale with DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to plot some Zernike polynomials, but I want all of them to be plotted by using the same colour scale from -1 to +1 (i.e. the range of these polynomials). I am using the following code:

```
DensityPlot[
  ZernikeR[n, m, Norm[{x, y}]] Cos[m ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1,1}
, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
, ColorFunction -> (Hue[2 (1 - #1)/3] &)
, PlotPoints -> 200
, PlotLegends -> Automatic
, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, -1 < x^2 + y^2 < 1]
]
```

I get what I want with some polynomials, e.g. when m=0 and n=2:

[image]

and not with others, e.g. when m=0 and n=4:

[image]

where the colour range goes down to -0.5 and not to -1. I want all polynomials to be coloured with a scale from -1 to 1, from blue to red. I haven't found a way to fix this. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Look up `ColorFunctionScaling` and `ColorFunction`.

Comment: `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` will prevent scaling but `2 (1 - #1)/3 &@Interval[{-1, 1}]` gives: `Interval[{0, 4/3}]` which can be missleading when `Hue` is applied ( {0,1} base domain). What exactly do you want to achieve, how your manual rescaling is related to the problem and are you only concerned about colors or the range in the bar legend aswell?

Comment: I'd like the color scale to always vary between blue set for -1 and red set for +1, independently from the min and max values of the function in that range.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100299)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This answer will be very similar to halirutan's answer (+1). The difference is that I preserved the color function from the OP, and that I made a fixed bar legend.)

We can do it like in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82952/731), which is to say, we can turn off the color function scaling and scale the values ourselves in a way that is the same for all plots. We can make our own bar legend that matches this scaling. We only need to change three options:

```
ColorFunction -> (Hue[2 (1 - Rescale[#1, {-1, 1}])/3] &),
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue[2 (1 - Rescale[#1, {-1, 1}])/3] &, {-1, 1}}]
```

Now we get plots like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi C.E., this is exactly the solution I just found thanks to the link you posted before. Thanks to all of you guys for you help.

Answer (score 4):

You have currently two mistakes. The first one is your color-function itself. It needs to give `Hue[0]` for a value of -1 and `Hue[1]` for a value of 1. The transformation is

```
col[v_] := Hue[Rescale[v, {-1, 1}]]
```

Secondly, you need to turn off that Mathematica rescales the values for each plot which can be done with the `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` option.

```
plot[m_, n_] := 
 DensityPlot[
  ZernikeR[n, m, Norm[{x, y}]] Cos[m ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  ColorFunction -> col, PlotPoints -> 200, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, -1 < x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

And then, `plot[0,2]` and `plot[0,4]` will use the same scaling for the colors:

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you don't want a circular color scheme like `Hue` is (begins and ends in red), then use one of the other schemes.